# How can I call a function in a funtion?

Tags: javascript, html

I want that the onclick event causes that the playerscore decrease and then check that the player win or not(playerscore==3 or not). I don't want to put the if statement into the onclick event. So how can i call it?

Example:

HTML:

```
<button onClick="myFunction()">button</button>
```

JS:

```
let playerScore = 0;
function myFunction() {
 playerScore++;
}
if (playerScore == 3) {
 console.log("win");
}
```

Comment: What is expected and what's the result here?

Comment: I think you are expecting the if condition to run on each button click ?. interpreter excutes the if condition during lexical phase and for each button click it calls the function not the if condition.

Comment: i want to show up "win" in conslone log if playerScore = 3, but doesn't work.

Comment: @sznajper If you don't make the code part of your function, then it wont be executed when the function is called. JavaScript doesn't keep a list of every if-statement and checks them all once any variable changes. Your if-statement s executed once at the very beginning (right after you declared your variable) and that's it.

Comment: @Ivar how can i made that the if statement always checks the varible?

Comment: You can put it inside a function (`checkForWin` for example) and then call that function from `myFunction` after you incremented the `playerScore`.

Comment: @Ivar so Should i put the function in a var in myFunction?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it in the function

```
let playerScore = 0;
function myFunction() {
 playerScore++;
if(playerScore == 3) {
 console.log("win");
}
}
```

If you want to export the if statement you can make a function and call it inside the first one

```
let playerScore = 0;
function myFunction() {
 playerScore++;
winner(playerScore);
}

function winner(playerScore){
if(playerScore == 3) {
 console.log("win");
}
}
```

Comment: what should i do if i want to move the if statement to an other js file?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do exactly. You can create a function and call it in the second js file. I added in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `if-statement` should be in the function, and the variable is misspelled:

```js
let playerScore = 0;
function myFunction() {
 playerScore++;
 if (playerScore == 3) {
  console.log("win");
 }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunction()">button</button>
```

Comment: what should i do if i want to move the if statement to an other js file?

Comment: You need to explain more. Do you want to keep it in the function and reuse the condition in another place?

Answer (score 0):

You had an typo in playerscore and the if had to be in the function.

```js
let playerScore = 0;
function myFunction() {
  playerScore++;

  if (playerScore == 3) {
    console.log("win");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunction()">button</button>
```

Comment: what should i do if i want to move the if statement to an other js file?